# I want to connect to iPhone's BLE through my BLE device

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy

The purpose of this task is to connect to iPhone's BLE through BLE device to access ANCS of iphone. Please note that there is no app installed in iPhone to turn ON BLE of iPhone.
So, If we enable Bluetooth from iPhone setting, will it enable BLE along with BT classic?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you enable BLE on an iPhone, you are enabling BT classic as well. The reason for this is that BLE is just a subset of the whole Bluetooth radio, along with BT classic. Since they use the same physical radio and chip, there is no way to enable BLE without turning on BT classic or vice versa. That being said, there is very limited functionality of BT classic on iPhones and most of that is restricted to developers unless you join the [MFi program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/).

For more information on the different Bluetooth subsets, please see this answer:-

[Can a Bluetooth LE powered device discover a classic Bluetooth device and vice-versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144934/can-a-bluetooth-le-powered-device-discover-a-classic-bluetooth-device-and-vice-v/23159699#23159699)

Please note that you will always have to enable Bluetooth manually on an iPhone and there is no way to enable this automatically.

I hope this helps.