# Can Android devices and PCs be treated as Bluetooth Low Energy devices?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Actually I am trying to use flutter_blue package which scans for nearby Bluetooth low energy devices. But that package is only scanning devices like Bluetooth earbuds, Bluetooth earphones and other similar devices but it is not scanning nearby phones which have Bluetooth turn down and it is also not able to scan Bluetooth in PCs.

[Screenshot of The results I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDYaO.jpg)

Comment: Bluetooth has two technologies: Bluetooth Classic and Bluetooth Low-Energy. Laptops and PCs continue to use Bluetooth Classic for a constant data stream at high throughput, and unlike smart devices, they rarely have to worry about power consumption.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144934/can-a-bluetooth-le-powered-device-discover-a-classic-bluetooth-device-and-vice-v#:~:text=No%20a%20BLE%20can%20not,it%20is%20advertising%20as%20BLE.

Comment: To communicate with a BT Classic-only device, you have to use the BT Classic approach; refer https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth For BLE devices, refer https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/ble-overview

Answer (score 2):

Bluetooth Low Energy is optimized for low energy consumption. One part of these optimizations is the ability to advertise the presence of a BLE device at different intervals, with lower intervals consuming less energy. You are only able to find BLE devices that are advertising its presence.

iOS devices can usually be found through their advertisements for the "Find my" network on their own. Android devices and PCs usually do not advertise their presence without an app present that needs this functionality.

There are many Android apps to help you develop and debug your BLE connection that can present themselves as BLE peripheral, one would be the [BLE Peripheral Simulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.github.webbluetoothcg.bletestperipheral).